# Where should I store nori or laver after opening, and for how much time?

Tags: storage-method, storage-lifetime, japanese-cuisine, korean-cuisine

My brother has given me laver for making Korean kimbap and there are ten “foils” or “sheets” in the package.

I have only used four of them today and I don't know whether I should cool or not the remaining ones. In my opinion the fridge might be too humid and humidity might have sheets stick to each other…

Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just keep it dry. I buy 100 sheets packs and store them in a zip-loc type bag in the cupboard for over a year

Comment: Also, if your nori comes with a little desiccant packet (mine does) don't throw that out, store it in the zip-lock with them, it absorbs the moisture for you.

Comment: Another tip: nori generally comes pre-toasted. You can give it a quick re-toast just before using. Just wave the sheet a few inches above a burner on your stove for a few seconds. Don't catch it on fire. That will remove any slight bit of moisture and improve the flavor.

Answer (score 0):

If the laver is roasted and seasoned (with oil and salt) it will only last for a day or so after opening depending on heat (oil becomes rancid) and humidity (seawead loses crisp texture). If it is dried seaweed it will keep indefinitely, however I believe it develops a stale taste unless stored in a cool dark place.